# Proving that if $f$ is an increasing function on $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{y \to x^{-}} f(y)$ and $\lim_{y \to x^{+}} f(y)$ exists.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to prove that if $f$ is a monotone increasing function on an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, then the limits

$\lim_{y \to x^{-}} f(y)$  and $\lim_{y \to x^{+}} f(y)$ exists.

My definition of monotone increasing is that $f$ is monotone increasing if

$f(x) \leq f(y)$ given $x,y \in I$ with $x \leq y$.

My approach is to look at infimum and supremum but am having difficulties. Does anyone know of a simple solution? Thank you!

Comment: What difficulties are you having?

Comment: You cannot arrive at the given conclusion unless it is given that $f$ is bounded. If it is given that $f$ is bounded(to be precise, an upper bound), you can use the least-upper-bound property of $\mathbb{R}$ to arrive that, it has a supremum $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and using the definition of supremum to arrive that $\lim$ is equal to $\sup$.

Comment: Any increasing function on an interval $I$ containing $x$ is bounded above (if the right endpoint of $I$ is contained in $I$) or else bounded above on a subinterval containing $x$.

Comment: The easiest approach is to look at $\sup f|_{I\cap(-\infty,x)}$ and $\inf f|_{I\cap(x,\infty)}$. - You need that $x$ is not the lower or upper end point of $I$, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x$ is not on the boundary of $I$. Then the set
$$\{f(y) : y < x\} $$
is bounded above by $f(x)$, and the set
$$\{f(y) : y > x\}$$ 
is bounded below by $f(x)$. Therefore
$$\sup \{f(y) : y < x\} \text{ and } \inf\{f(y) : y > x\}$$
exist in $\mathbb{R}$.

I will show that $\lim_{y\rightarrow x^-} f(y) = \sup \{f(y) : y < x\}$.

Let $\epsilon> 0$ be given, by the definition of supreme, there exist a $y_0<x$ such that 
$$\sup \{f(y) : y < x\} - f(y_0) \leq \epsilon,$$
and because $f$ is monotone increasing, for each $y\in [y_0, x)$, we have 
$$\sup \{f(y) : y < x\} - f(y) \leq \sup \{f(y) : y < x\} - f(y_0) \leq \epsilon,$$
which is precisely the definition of $\lim_{y\rightarrow x^-} f(y) = \sup \{f(y) : y < x\}$.